# Transferring photos and videos in bulk from Pixel 4a to Windows PC

Tags: windows, video, android, file-transfer, photos

Every few months I transfer photos and videos from my Pixel 4a phone to my  Windows computer over USB. The process is slow, which I can somewhat tolerate. But it is also labor intensive and prone to errors.

Labor intensive: I have to preview the video/image (which has a noticeable delay because I'm accessing it via my computer connected through USB to my phone), copy, paste, and then delete the original, manually, every time. Why do I have to do it like this?

Error prone:
It is seemingly impossible to do in bulk; trying to copy/paste any more than one video at a time almost always causes my computer to freeze, and using "cut" instead of "copy" is a risk I am not willing to take for that reason. I haven't bothered transferring many photos because it barely seems worth the time to go through all of them individually, and it's not worth the risk of losing them if I try to transfer a bunch at once.

Also: when I am transferring videos, I start getting "cannot modify file as it's in use" popups with gradually increasing frequency when I try to copy them.

Also: I have to kludge my phone into staying unlocked by "pinning" the photos app. This does not prevent my screen from darkening, which does seem to cause slowdown so I also have to be constantly tapping my phone's screen throughout the transfer process. Plus, I don't know which is worse: having the photos app open, thereby meaning that my phone and computer are trying to access them simultaneously, or having some other app open, which might cause problems for some other reason.

I am using a USB 3.0 cable, but I wonder if part of the issue is that the USB port on my phone is either worn down or simply not designed for heavy data  transfer. Which makes sense; Google wants me  to subscribe to their cloud service. But I don't want to. I want to find a way to make my own process more efficient. Any suggestions?

Update (8-16-2023): Tried doing this again, using my old method, and discovered that it's significantly worse than it used to be. If I view anything on my phone via my computer, it gives me a "resource already in use" error if I subsequently try to copy/paste, or even if I so much as try to view something else. This error used to be something that would happen with increasing frequency; now it is something that is guaranteed to happen. The only way to resume copying/pasting files seems to be unplugging/replugging my phone and starting the process over, or waiting some indeterminate amount of time after viewing something to try viewing something else. I will see if any of the suggestions help, as they are now needed more than ever.

Comment: One thing I can suggest for you is to adopt some sort of naming convention for your files.  I'm not sure what it is exactly you need to sieve or filter through when you state that you need to preview them and choose what to copy and paste, but if you make a habit of naming them as you go, then when it comes time to upload or transfer them, you would be able to sort by name, and know without previewing the files that the ones starting with, e.g., *abc* go here, and *def* go there, etc.

Comment: That's a good idea generally, but I run into two issues. The first is that naming pictures and videos on your phone is a bit of a pain. The second is that sometimes the autogenerated titles are the only accurate record I have of the time and date when something was taken, which is important to me. Eventually I want to add in descriptions, keywords, etc. into the metadata, but that'll be an ordeal unto itself for sure.

Comment: Best way I know of to go about what you're looking to do is via command line transfer using `adb`, of which avoids every problem you're encountering. In general, regardless of OS, command line transfer is almost always, if not always, faster _(throughput & transfer time)_ than doing so through the GUI _(it's also usually more efficient when a large number of files are involved)_. More frequently than you, I transfer thousands of files and hundreds of GB from my phone to my laptop and I can move ~300GB of data from a Pixel 6/7 ~45min _(+/- ~15min depending on file size and number of files)_.

Comment: Another route: if the pixel's File Explorer app doesn't support SMB, look into an app that allows you to browse your Windows shared folders and then you can copy/cut and paste the files over your network. One such app is CIFS Documents Provider, but this link has a list of possible apps with tested transfer speeds ( https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/136d5h6/file_transfer_speed_comparison_of_file_managers/ )

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the used MTP protocol used for file-transfer. This protocol was designed by Microsoft long time ago, for tiny devices with a few hundred KB RAM and a few MB flash memory, not recent devices with 100 or more GB and plenty of RAM.

For this reason MTP is very limited, for example it only allows one command at a time, so if you copy something the whole device is blocked even for listing files in a directory.

Luckily Android includes an alternative protocol which is capable of processing multiple commands at the same time and this protocol is also more reliable: Android Debug Bridge. You need to enable developer options on the Android phone (usually taping 5 times the Android build number in Android settings) and then enable in the developer setting Android Debug Bridge (ADB).

On PC side you need Android SDK or "Minimal ADB" package and for some devices a driver package to recognize adb interface.
For Google devices you can find a ZIP file that contains the drivers here: [Google USB drivers version 13](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/usb_driver_r13-windows.zip). A small tutorial how to install the drivers can be found e.g. [here](https://www.getdroidtips.com/google-usb-drivers/#Method-2-Manual-Download-of-Google-USB-Drivers). For installing adb you can refer to the tutorial on XDA: [How to install ADB on Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/).

Then you can use adb based tools like `adb-sync` (unfortunately Google stopped development) or it' successor [better-adb-sync](https://github.com/jb2170/better-adb-sync). There are also GUI tools like "ADB explorer" available that use adb in background, I don't know how good they are, I prefer command-line.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I remember reading somewhere about the USB2 thing but couldn't confirm if it was true with Pixel 4a. Are there any tutorials for getting the Android SDK/minimal ADB thing set up? Preferably a Pixel 4a-specific one (I'm very easily confused/discouraged by this stuff lol)

Comment: @Undine I have added some links on adb installation.

Comment: Okay! I'm trying to use Better ADB Sync. I have installed the Android SDK. The tutorial I'm reading tells me to make sure ADB is in my PATH. I don't know what that means or how to make it happen.

Comment: Actually, I went for ADB Explorer, the GUI tool you mentioned. It seems to run more stably than Windows Expllorer, but it doesn't allow me to view the videos or photos. I tried having Windows Explorer open in addition to the GUI tool, but then I just ran into the same "resource already in use" error as before.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to transfer files from Android to a PC is always via [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb) [Android Debug Bridge]; however, if the videos are saved to `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`, they'll be intermingled with photos and will need to be processed as wildcards [`*.mp4`] to copy all files with that extension.

---

### Prerequisites

1. **Download and extract [`platform-tools`](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools) directory to [`%ProgramData%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-folderlocations-programdata)**
2. **Open PowerShell / Cmd terminal:** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `powershell` || `cmd` → OK

   1. **Add `platform-tools` to `$env:PATH` / `%PATH%`:**

      ```powershell
      # Once executed, close and reopen terminal:
        Cmd /c Setx /M Path "%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\platform-tools;"
      ```
3. **USB Debugging must first be [enabled](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#Enabling) via [Developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable) to use `adb`:**

   1. **Settings** → **About Phone** || → **Software Info** || →  **More**
   2. Tap ***Build Number*** 7x until ***You are now a developer!*** shows
   3. **Settings** → *Search Settings*: `debugging` → **USB Debugging**

---

### 4.1 Copy `*.jpg` || `*.mp4` Wildcard Files

1. **Phone → PC:**

   - **PowerShell:**

     ```powershell
     # JPG [photos]:
       adb shell ls "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.jpg" | foreach {adb pull -a -p "$_"}

     # MP4 [videos]:
       adb shell ls "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4" | foreach {adb pull -a -p "$_"}
     ```
   - **Cmd:** 
      *(Must be executed from within directory files will be saved to)*

     ```powershell
     # JPG [photos]:
       for /F "delims=" %I in ('adb shell find "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.jpg"') do (adb pull -a -p "%I")

     # MP4 [videos]:
       for /F "delims=" %I in ('adb shell find "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4"') do (adb pull -a -p "%I")
     ```
2. **PC → Phone:**

   - **PowerShell:**

     ```powershell
     # JPG [photos]:
       ls ".\*.jpg" | foreach {adb push -a -p "$_" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"}

     # MP4 [videos]:
       ls ".\*.mp4" | foreach {adb push -a -p "$_" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"}
     ```
   - **Cmd:**

     ```powershell
     # JPG [photos]:
       for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir ".\*.jpg" /B /O:-D') do (adb push -a -p ".\%I" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder/")

     # MP4 [videos]:
       for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir ".\*.mp4" /B /O:-D') do (adb push -a -p ".\%I" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder/")
     ```

---

### 4.2 Copy Directories

1. **Phone → PC:**

   ```powershell
   # To current directory:
     adb pull -a -p "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder" .

   # To specific directory:
     adb pull -a -p "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder" "D:\Path\to\Folder"
   ```
2. **PC → Phone:**

   ```bash
   # From current directory:
     adb push -a -p "..\<current folder>" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"

   # From specific directory:
     adb push -a -p "D:\Path\to\Folder" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"
   ```

---

### 4.3 Copy Files

1. **Phone → PC:**

   ```powershell
   # To current directory:
     adb pull -a -p "/sdcard/Path/to/File" .

   # To specific directory:
     adb pull -a -p "/sdcard/Path/to/File" "D:\Path\to\Folder"
   ```
2. **PC → Phone:**

   ```bash
   # From current directory:
     adb push -a -p ".\<file>" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"

   # From specific directory:
     adb push -a -p "D:\Path\to\File" "/sdcard/Path/to/Folder"
   ```

---

### 5. Cleanup

1. **Remove copied files from Phone:**

   ```bash
   # This will not prompt for confirmation (for confirmation, remove -f)

     # Delete Photos and Videos:
       adb shell rm -f "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*"

     # Delete only Photos:
       adb shell rm -f "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.jpg"

     # Delete only Videos:
       adb shell rm -f "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4"
   ```
2. ***Disable USB Debugging* → Disconnect Phone** 
    *ADB can often be added to Quick Tiles for easy enabling/disabling of USB Debugging, as leaving it enabled when not in use is a data security issue (never enable wireless ADB, it's not secure):* [image: Screenshot]

---

### [`adb <pull | push>`](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#copyfiles)

```bash
# ADB File Transfer:

  # Copy files/directories from device:
    adb pull [-a] [-z ALGORITHM] [-Z] REMOTE... LOCAL
      -a: preserve file timestamp and mode
      -p: display transfer progress
      -z: enable compression with a specified algorithm (any/none/brotli/lz4/zstd)
      -Z: disable compression

  # Copy local files/directories to device:
    adb push [--sync] [-z ALGORITHM] [-Z] LOCAL... REMOTE
      -a: preserve file timestamp and mode
      -n: dry run: push files to device without storing to the filesystem
      -p: display transfer progress
      -z: enable compression with a specified algorithm (any/none/brotli/lz4/zstd)
      -Z: disable compression
      --sync: only push files that are newer on the host than the device
```

---

### Reference Sources

- StackOverflow:

  - [adb pull multiple files with the same extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863549/adb-pull-multiple-files-with-the-same-extension)
  - [adb pull multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files)
  - [Copy file with `FOR /F %I IN () DO (copy)` command, file contain space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531407/copy-file-with-for-f-i-in-do-copy-command-file-contain-space)

Answer (score 1):

For transferring phone pics to my computer, I use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/). You install it on your PC, and there's an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.catfriend1.syncthingandroid&hl=en&gl=US).

When you've set up Syncthing on both devices: on your phone, connect your PC as a device (it'll just appear if you're on the same network), and share your photos folder. On your PC, accept the share request and your photos will start transferring over. Any change on either device will (by default) be synced across both devices, so new pics will appear on your PC, and any that you delete will be deleted on both. (I usually transfer pics out of that shared folder into a permanent home on my PC, to save on phone storage space.)

The setup is fairly simple and no cables are required. Syncthing is a little resource-intensive, but you can set it up so that it only runs when your phone is plugged in, to save battery. It can use either data or WiFi connections; transfer speeds are pretty good if both devices are on the same WiFi network.

Comment: Great idea =] It may not fit with what the OP is looking for since they also want to remove the copied files after copying, which would also delete files from the sync server and all clients

Comment: No, that's exactly what I do too. I move the files out of the 'Camera Roll' folder into a more permanent home on my PC - somewhere that's not synced with my phone. To Syncthing, those files just got removed from a shared folder, so they're deleted on the phone too.

Comment: The issue is the save location, as I'm unsure if the location can modified from `DCIM` for default camera apps; the next question would be do all phones allow modification of the save location to a location other than `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`? There are secondary solutions you could configure, such as a basic script using [MacroDroid,](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) that auto moves photos and videos from `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera` to the SyncThing directory

Comment: My phone (Android 12) saves to `/[external]/DCIM`, which is set up as a Syncthing folder. No need to change the save location.

Comment: Most Android devices don't offer microsd cards as an option since it's a security risk - most OEMs began phasing that out ~2015, and while some still offer a microsd card slot, it's the exception, not the norm. I still think your answer is a great idea, there's simply some caveats to it is all =]

Answer (score 0):

Google's [specifications](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7158570) show that the Pixel 4a has USB3 (USB 3.1 gen 1), so you ought to be able to get decent transfer speeds over USB.  While you say you have a USB3 cable, you need to check that it is plugged into a USB3 port on your laptop (some have a mix of USB2 and USB3 - USB 3 are normally blue).  Also check that the cable really is USB3-capable, not just a USB2 cable with a USB-C connector at one end ([Google say](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7106961?hl=en-GB#:%7E:text=Pixel%20phones%20use%20USB%2DC,not%20work%20with%20Pixel%20phones.) they supply the Pixel 4a with a USB2 cable for charging...)  Using adaptors like a Micro USB to USB-C adaptor would also be likely to drop you down to USB2 speeds.

If the USB connection is OK, the problem is most likely that the laptop is trying to read your photos to generate thumbnails at the same time that it is copying them.  This slows things down, as well as generating the "file in use" errors.  If you are using Windows Explorer to copy the files, then you can avoid this by selecting the "Details" view from the View ribbon, rather than one of the icon views.  You might also want to check that you haven't got any other software on the laptop that tries to copy your photos when you plug your phone in, e.g. Dropbox or another cloud storage or automatic backup programme.

Personally, I have not found it necessary to have the Photos app open on my phone while copying photos to a laptop, or to keep the phone unlocked once I've allowed USB access.  My transfer procedure is like this:

1. Plug phone into laptop via USB cable.
2. Unlock phone, choose the USB charging notification, and set it to allow file or photo transfer.
3. Open Windows Explorer on the laptop, find the phone in My Computer, and navigate to the DCIM folder where the photos are.
4. Set the Windows Explorer view to "Details" and wait for the list to populate.
5. Drag and drop the photos I want onto the appropriate laptop folder (identifying them by their filename or file date).

Another option you could perhaps investigate is using WiFi to transfer your photos.  If you are able to share a folder on your laptop, you can transfer photos to it from your phone using an Android file manager app like Cx File Explorer.  This is theoretically slower than USB3, but might give you better results if you have problems with the USB connection.  Pushing the photos from the phone in this way would also avoid the problem of other Windows apps trying to read them at the same time.

Another potential workaround, if you are using the Google Photos app on your phone and allowing it to back up your pictures, is just to go to https://photos.google.com/ on your laptop and download them.  You can select the ones you want and download them as a batch.  Unless you have a very fast internet connection on the laptop, this is likely to be slower than the other options, but it doesn't need any software to be set up.

Comment: Also very helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site.  If you find any of the answers helpful, remember to upvote them, and if your problem is solved, tick to accept whichever answer worked best for you.  This helps people find good answers quickly in the future.

Comment: Tried following at least one part of your advice, using the "details" view instead of the thumbnail previews. No dice. I don't appear to have any app like Dropbox running, so I really don't know what the problem is. My theory is that the media player continues running in the background after I've used it, or something like that.